# How to extract JSON object from JSON array using JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have this kind of JSON:

```
"[{\"domain\": \"domain.com\", \"adminEmail\": \"test@example.com\", \"ipAddress\": \"1.1.1.1\", \"admin\": \"admin\", \"package\": \"Default\", \"state\": \"Active\"},{\"domain\": \"domain2.com\", \"adminEmail\": \"test@example.com\", \"ipAddress\": \"8.8.8.8\", \"admin\": \"admin2\", \"package\": \"Default\", \"state\": \"Active\"},{\"domain\": \"domain3.com\", \"adminEmail\": \"test@domain3.com\", \"ipAddress\": \"8.8.4.4\", \"admin\": \"admin3\", \"package\": \"Default\", \"state\": \"Active\"}]"
```

I want to extract a domain list that has the state "Active".

Example:

```
jq 'some command' my.json
```

Will print:

```
domain.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
```

Every command that I tried I get the same error:

```
jq: error (at test.json:1): Cannot iterate over string ("[{\"domain...)
```

The JSON seems to be valid for me. One thing that I observed is python3 json.tool module can not print this JSON formatted. I do not know why.

I am trying to avoid to create a script to read this JSON. I want some tool that can read from command line pipe and print the domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jq '.[] | select(.state=="Active") | .domain' my.json
```

output:

```
domain.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
```

Comment: This is what I tried. With the @evert answer it was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

As @Inian pointed out, the key here is to use `fromjson`.  Putting it all together:

```
jq -r 'fromjson[] | select(.state=="Active") | .domain'
```

Comment: Never used that. Excellent! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is a JSON-encoded object, but then that string is re-encoded using JSON again.

So you'll first need to find a way to decode the JSON, and output the result of that back into a new file.

To do this with jq:

```
jq -r input1.json > input2.json
```

Now your `input2.json` is a regular json file that you can normally execute jq commands on.